# Why are bundle and rails commands unavailable at command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler, homebrew

Earlier this year, I installed Ruby 2.0 with Homebrew and built a Rails 3.2 project on a Mac running OS X Mountain Lion.  The project ran fine.

I am not (and was not) using rvm or rbenv on this machine.

In the months since I ran last rails, I have re-installed Xcode and Xcode command line tools, but I'm still running Mountain Lion.  And now when I attempt to run Rails I get this error:

```
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Ruby and RubyGems are both sourced from my Homebrew install directory:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

$ which gem
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem
$ gem -v
2.0.3
```

When I run gem list, I see a long list of things I expect: all of the actionxxx gems, bundler, rack, rails 3.2, etc.

But I can't run the bundle command and the rails command is pointing to the OS X version:

```
$ bundle list
-bash: bundle: command not found

$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the binstub files for bundle and rails were missing in my (gem env) EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY.

I ran 'gem update --system' to get the latest RubyGem installed.

I ran `gem update bundler` to generate the bundle binstub.

I tried uninstalling, then re-installing Rails 3.2.12, but that didn't help.  I thought there might be an issue with railties, so I ran `gem update railties`, which had the apparent side-effect of creating the rails binstub.  And that solved the problem with rails not found:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.12
```